Clang 17 cannot find <format> to convert chrono timepoint to string
I have a std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point I would like to convert to string.
I wanted to use this:
#include <format>

std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp;
std::string s = std::format("{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}", tp);

I am using Clang 17 with -std=c++2b on Linux and unfortunately this produces the error:
fatal error: 'format' file not found

Is there another way to achieve this?
I'd like to stick with std::chrono timepoints but I don't mind using Boost format.

Check the version of libc++ you have. If it's below 17, you will need -fexperimental-library flag to enable <format>, If it's below 14, you're out of luck. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features

Had to add a couple extra headers, but otherwise Compiler Explorer had no problems: https://godbolt.org/z/bG3cvxhvb

Also, integration of <chrono> and <format> is labelled as "partial support" here: https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/Cxx20.html#id6. You may need a different library or wait until it's implemented fully...

@user4581301 godbolt uses libstdc++ by default on both gcc and clang, if you want typical clang behaviour add -stdlib=libc++: https://godbolt.org/z/TPTGb1Kn6

Ah ha! Sneeeeeeaky!

high_resolution_clock can not be portably streamed out in this fashion, even in C++20.  This is because high_resolution_clock is (in practice) a type alias for either steady_clock or system_clock.  When using the gcc libstdc++ it is an alias for system_clock, and when using llvm's libc++ it is an alias for steady_clock.
steady_clock can not be streamed out in this fashion because it has no relationship to the civil calendar.  It is like a stopwatch.  It can time something for you.  But it can't tell you the time of day.
system_clock can tell you the time of day.
https://godbolt.org/z/vr8E8GoqM
